# Прилипающий длинный сайдбар

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать что-бы сайдбар двигался вместе с основной частью,но при скроле до конца сайдбара он должен принимать фиксированную позицию.
При скроле вверх,когда сайдбар в фиксированном позиции,сайдбар должен двигаться с основной частью.

https://jsfiddle.net/z0bjLv32/

```
    <main>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>2</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>3</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>4</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>5</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>6</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>7</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>8</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>9</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>10</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>11</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>12</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>13</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>14</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>15</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>16</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>17</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>18</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>19</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>20</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>21</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>22</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>23</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>24</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>25</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>26</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>27</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>28</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>29</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>30</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>31</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>32</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>33</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>34</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>35</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>36</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>37</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>38</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>39</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>40</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>41</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>42</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>43</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>44</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>45</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>46</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>47</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>48</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>49</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>50</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>51</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>52</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>53</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>54</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>55</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>56</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>57</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>58</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>59</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>60</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>61</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>62</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>63</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>64</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>65</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>66</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>67</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>68</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>69</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>70</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>71</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>72</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>73</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>74</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>75</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>76</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>77</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>78</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>79</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>80</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>81</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>82</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>83</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>84</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>85</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>86</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>87</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>88</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>89</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>90</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>91</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>92</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>93</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>94</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>95</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>96</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>97</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>98</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>99</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>100</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</main>
<aside>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>2</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>3</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>4</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>5</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>6</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>7</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>8</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>9</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>10</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>11</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>12</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>13</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>14</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>15</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>16</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>17</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>18</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>19</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>20</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>21</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>22</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>23</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>24</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>25</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>26</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>27</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>28</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>29</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>30</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>31</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>32</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>33</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>34</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>35</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>36</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>37</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>38</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>39</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>40</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>41</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>42</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>43</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>44</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>45</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>46</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>47</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>48</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>49</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>50</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>51</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>52</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>53</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>54</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>55</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>56</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>57</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>58</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>59</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>60</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>61</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>62</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>63</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>64</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>65</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>66</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>67</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>68</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>69</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>70</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/sticky-elements-jquery-plugins/  вот с массой примеров

Answer (score 2):

Недавно делал такое

```js
(function(){
var a = document.querySelector('#aside1'), b = null, K = null, Z = 0, P = 0, N = 0;  // если у P ноль заменить на число, то блок будет прилипать до того, как верхний край окна браузера дойдёт до верхнего края элемента, если у N — нижний край дойдёт до нижнего края элемента. Может быть отрицательным числом
window.addEventListener('scroll', Ascroll, false);
document.body.addEventListener('scroll', Ascroll, false);
function Ascroll() {
  var Ra = a.getBoundingClientRect(),
      R1bottom = document.querySelector('#article').getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  if (Ra.bottom < R1bottom) {
    if (b == null) {
      var Sa = getComputedStyle(a, ''), s = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < Sa.length; i++) {
        if (Sa[i].indexOf('overflow') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('padding') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('border') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('outline') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('box-shadow') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('background') == 0) {
          s += Sa[i] + ': ' +Sa.getPropertyValue(Sa[i]) + '; '
        }
      }
      b = document.createElement('div');
      b.className = "stop";
      b.style.cssText = s + ' box-sizing: border-box; width: ' + a.offsetWidth + 'px;';
      a.insertBefore(b, a.firstChild);
      var l = a.childNodes.length;
      for (var i = 1; i < l; i++) {
        b.appendChild(a.childNodes[1]);
      }
      a.style.height = b.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
      a.style.padding = '0';
      a.style.border = '0';
    }
    var Rb = b.getBoundingClientRect(),
        Rh = Ra.top + Rb.height,
        W = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        R1 = Math.round(Rh - R1bottom),
        R2 = Math.round(Rh - W);
    if (Rb.height > W) {
      if (Ra.top < K) {  // скролл вниз
        if (R2 + N > R1) {  // не дойти до низа
          if (Rb.bottom - W + N <= 0) {  // подцепиться
            b.className = 'sticky';
            b.style.top = W - Rb.height - N + 'px';
            Z = N + Ra.top + Rb.height - W;
          } else {
            b.className = 'stop';
            b.style.top = - Z + 'px';
          }
        } else {
          b.className = 'stop';
          b.style.top = - R1 +'px';
          Z = R1;
        }
      } else {  // скролл вверх
        if (Ra.top - P < 0) {  // не дойти до верха
          if (Rb.top - P >= 0) {  // подцепиться
            b.className = 'sticky';
            b.style.top = P + 'px';
            Z = Ra.top - P;
          } else {
            b.className = 'stop';
            b.style.top = - Z + 'px';
          }
        } else {
          b.className = '';
          b.style.top = '';
          Z = 0;
        }
      }
      K = Ra.top;
    } else {
      if ((Ra.top - P) <= 0) {
        if ((Ra.top - P) <= R1) {
          b.className = 'stop';
          b.style.top = - R1 +'px';
        } else {
          b.className = 'sticky';
          b.style.top = P + 'px';
        }
      } else {
        b.className = '';
        b.style.top = '';
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
      a.children[0].style.width = getComputedStyle(a, '').width
    }, false);
  }
}
})()
```

```css
#article{
  height: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#aside1{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
}
.stop {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <article id="article"></article>
  <aside id="aside1">
    Lorem Ipsum - це текст-"риба", що використовується в друкарстві та дизайні. Lorem Ipsum є, фактично, стандартною "рибою" аж з XVI сторіччя, коли невідомий друкар взяв шрифтову гранку та склав на ній підбірку зразків шрифтів. "Риба" не тільки успішно пережила п'ять століть, але й прижилася в електронному верстуванні, залишаючись по суті незмінною. Вона популяризувалась в 60-их роках минулого сторіччя завдяки виданню зразків шрифтів Letraset, які містили уривки з Lorem Ipsum, і вдруге - нещодавно завдяки програмам комп'ютерного верстування на кшталт Aldus Pagemaker, які використовували різні версії Lorem Ipsum.
  </aside>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Источник: http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/09/scroll-block.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать [sticky-kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/)